# How to format /etc/passwd file using perl formatting

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I'm trying to format the /etc/passwd file by using perl formatting

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

format MYFORMAT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$username,        $UID,             $name
.

$username = `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`;
$UID = `cut -d: -f3 /etc/passwd`;
$name = `cut -d: -f5 /etc/passwd`;

$~ = "MYFORMAT";
write;
```

I receive no warnings or errors. The formatting works, but the issue is, it only displays the first line of the etc/passwd file. I only get root, 0, and root as the Username, UID and name respectively.

I need all usernames, UIDs, and names printed for each column. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because when I run the bash command to get only the usernames inside the terminal, it displays all of them. It won't do it inside of the script though.

Comment: I don't receive any warnings, I changed the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looping over the /etc/passwd file, you're getting back the first set of fields into your variables, but then only using the first.  Consider this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$username = `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`;
print $username;
```

Instead try perl myscript.pl < /etc/passwd with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $username;
my $UID;
my $name;

format =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$username,        $UID,             $name
.

while (<>) {
    ($username, undef, $UID, undef, $name, undef) = split(':');
    write();
}
```

Output looks like:

```
~/tmp$ perl t2.pl < /etc/passwd
root            | 0               | root
daemon          | 1               | daemon
bin             | 2               | bin
sys             | 3               | sys
sync            | 4               | sync
games           | 5               | games
```

If you don't give your format a name, STDOUT is the default.  And you can read in each line from /etc/passwd and process individually.